# error during pip install -r requirements.txt of threestudio

Tags: python, pip

I'm failing on this line (`pip install git+https://github.com/KAIR-BAIR/nerfacc.git@v0.5.2`) using Ubuntu for Windows:

```
andy@andys-pc:/threestudio$ pip install git+https://github.com/KAIR-BAIR/nerfacc.git@v0.5.2
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting git+https://github.com/KAIR-BAIR/nerfacc.git@v0.5.2
Cloning https://github.com/KAIR-BAIR/nerfacc.git (to revision v0.5.2) to /tmp/pip-req-build-vu8gv1bc
Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/KAIR-BAIR/nerfacc.git /tmp/pip-req-build-vu8gv1bc
Running command git checkout -q d84cdf3afd7dcfc42150e0f0506db58a5ce62812
Resolved https://github.com/KAIR-BAIR/nerfacc.git to commit d84cdf3afd7dcfc42150e0f0506db58a5ce62812
Running command git submodule update --init --recursive -q
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: rich>=12 in /home/andy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from nerfacc==0.5.2) (13.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: torch in /home/andy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from nerfacc==0.5.2) (1.12.1+cu113)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments<3.0.0,>=2.13.0 in /home/andy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from rich>=12->nerfacc==0.5.2) (2.16.1)
Requirement already satisfied: markdown-it-py>=2.2.0 in /home/andy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from rich>=12->nerfacc==0.5.2) (3.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in /home/andy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from torch->nerfacc==0.5.2) (4.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: mdurl=0.1 in /home/andy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from markdown-it-py>=2.2.0->rich>=12->nerfacc==0.5.2) (0.1.2)
Building wheels for collected packages: nerfacc
Building wheel for nerfacc (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [540 lines of output]
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/nerfacc
copying nerfacc/pdf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/nerfacc
copying nerfacc/grid.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/nerfacc
copying nerfacc/pack.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/nerfacc
copying nerfacc/version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/nerfacc
copying nerfacc/cameras2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/nerfacc
copying nerfacc/init.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/nerfacc
copying nerfacc/cameras.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/nerfacc
copying nerfacc/volrend.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/nerfacc
copying nerfacc/scan.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/nerfacc
copying nerfacc/data_specs.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/nerfacc
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/nerfacc/estimators
copying nerfacc/estimators/occ_grid.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/nerfacc/estimators
copying nerfacc/estimators/init.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/nerfacc/estimators
copying nerfacc/estimators/prop_net.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/nerfacc/estimators
copying nerfacc/estimators/base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/nerfacc/estimators
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/nerfacc/cuda
copying nerfacc/cuda/init.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/nerfacc/cuda
copying nerfacc/cuda/backend.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/nerfacc/cuda
running egg_info
creating nerfacc.egg-info
writing nerfacc.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to nerfacc.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to nerfacc.egg-info/requires.txt
writing top-level names to nerfacc.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing manifest file 'nerfacc.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest file 'nerfacc.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching 'nerfacc/cuda/csrc/include/'
warning: no files found matching 'nerfacc/_cuda/csrc/'
adding license file 'LICENSE'
writing manifest file 'nerfacc.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/nerfacc/cuda/csrc
copying nerfacc/cuda/csrc/camera.cu -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/nerfacc/cuda/csrc
copying nerfacc/cuda/csrc/grid.cu -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/nerfacc/cuda/csrc
copying nerfacc/cuda/csrc/nerfacc.cpp -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/nerfacc/cuda/csrc
copying nerfacc/cuda/csrc/pdf.cu -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/nerfacc/cuda/csrc
copying nerfacc/cuda/csrc/scan.cu -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/nerfacc/cuda/csrc
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/nerfacc/cuda/csrc/include
copying nerfacc/cuda/csrc/include/data_spec.hpp -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/nerfacc/cuda/csrc/include
copying nerfacc/cuda/csrc/include/data_spec_packed.cuh -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/nerfacc/cuda/csrc/include
copying nerfacc/cuda/csrc/include/utils_camera.cuh -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/nerfacc/cuda/csrc/include
copying nerfacc/cuda/csrc/include/utils_contraction.cuh -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/nerfacc/cuda/csrc/include
copying nerfacc/cuda/csrc/include/utils_cuda.cuh -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/nerfacc/cuda/csrc/include
copying nerfacc/cuda/csrc/include/utils_grid.cuh -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/nerfacc/cuda/csrc/include
copying nerfacc/cuda/csrc/include/utils_math.cuh -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/nerfacc/cuda/csrc/include
copying nerfacc/cuda/csrc/include/utils_scan.cuh -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/nerfacc/cuda/csrc/include
running build_ext
/home/andy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py:813: UserWarning: The detected CUDA version (11.5) has a minor version mismatch with the version that was used to compile PyTorch (11.3). Most likely this shouldn't be a problem.
warnings.warn(CUDA_MISMATCH_WARN.format(cuda_str_version, torch.version.cuda))
/home/andy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py:820: UserWarning: There are no x86_64-linux-gnu-g++ version bounds defined for CUDA version 11.5
warnings.warn(f'There are no {compiler_name} version bounds defined for CUDA version {cuda_str_version}')
building 'nerfacc.csrc' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10/nerfacc
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10/nerfacc/cuda
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10/nerfacc/cuda/csrc
/usr/bin/nvcc -Inerfacc/cuda/csrc/include -I/home/andy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/include -I/home/andy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include -I/home/andy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/include/TH -I/home/andy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/include/THC -I/usr/include/python3.10 -c nerfacc/cuda/csrc/camera.cu -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10/nerfacc/cuda/csrc/camera.o -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_OPERATORS -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_CONVERSIONS__ -D__CUDA_NO_BFLOAT16_CONVERSIONS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF2_OPERATORS__ --expt-relaxed-constexpr --compiler-options '-fPIC' -O3 --expt-relaxed-constexpr -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H -DPYBIND11_COMPILER_TYPE="_gcc" -DPYBIND11_STDLIB="_libstdcpp" -DPYBIND11_BUILD_ABI="_cxxabi1011" -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=csrc -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -gencode=arch=compute_86,code=compute_86 -gencode=arch=compute_86,code=sm_86 -std=c++14
/usr/include/c++/11/type_traits(1406): error: type name is not allowed

  /usr/include/c++/11/type_traits(1406): error: type name is not allowed

  /usr/include/c++/11/type_traits(1406): error: identifier "__is_same" is undefined
```

Comment: It would be nice to share the `pip` and `python` versions that you are using.